# Get radio value not working in safari, but in mozilla

Tags: javascript, safari

This works in IE Mozilla Chrome etc.
This works not in Safari.
foo is value from radio button by name

```
alert(document.form.foo.value);
```

The Value in IE Mozilla Chrome is correct.
In Safari is the Value "undefined".

Comment: Your post is tagged incorrectly. It should be javascript, not java.

Comment: please provide enough code (including html) to replicate problem.

Comment: @ollien, I also don't see any mention of jQuery in the question.  Removed [tag:jquery] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code to explain ?

Use jQuery to do this :

```
$('input[name=radio_Name]:checked', '#myForm').val();
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05wyqpvm/2/)

Comment: The OP never mentioned anything about jQuery so he never should have tagged it as such.